# How to change owner of mount point

Tags: unix, mount, permissions, fstab

We have moved mysql data directory to another disk, so now `/var/lib/mysql` is just a mount point to another partition. We set the owner of the `/var/lib/mysql` directory to `mysql.mysql`.

But everytime we mount the partition, the ownership changes to `root.root`. Because of this, we couldn't create additional MySQL database.

Our fstab entry:

```
/dev/mapper/db-db   /var/lib/mysql    ext3    relatime        0       2
```

How to change the owner of mount point to user other than root?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You need to change the permissions of the mounted filesystem, not of the mount point when the filesystem is not mounted. So `mount /var/lib/mysql` then `chown mysql.mysql /var/lib/mysql`. This will change the permissions of the root of the MySQL DB filesystem.

The basic idea is that the filesystem holding the DB needs to be changed, not the mount point, unless its path has some issues, e.g. `lib` can only be read by root.

Answer (score 50):

also

```
mount device mount-point -o uid=foo -o gid=foo
```

if group need to be changed too

Comment: Where the uid `foo` is the name of the user you want to be the owner of the mount point. And gid `foo` is the name of the user group, generally the same as the user name. In doubt just type `ls -l` in your home directory and check the first and second names respectively.

Comment: This only works on filesystems that don't store UNIX ownership, like vfat and ntfs.

Answer (score 16):

### Important disclaimer (learned that from comments):

> uid and gid flags only work on filesystems that don't support Linux
> permissions schema - ie, FAT and NTFS, among others

**Thus this is NOT a correct answer to OP but helpful to others**

---

Add uid and gid like these:

```
/dev/mapper/db-db  /var/lib/mysql ext3  relatime,rw,exec,uid=frank,gid=www-group        0       2
```

You can use actual user/groupnames (beware of spaces) or numeric uid, gid values.
I added rw and exec which might further help you prevent access troubles (presuming you are on a development system, not a production server).

PS: For even more access (if desired), add ",dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777"

Comment: No, it's `relatime`.  http://lwn.net/Articles/244829/

Comment: -1 because `uid` and `gid` flags only work on filesystems that *don't* support Linux permissions schema - ie, FAT and NTFS, among others. See http://askubuntu.com/a/34068/329506

Comment: yeah,i ran into the uid/gid issue - is there a solution?

Comment: This helped me with my FAT32 drive. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

Make sure you change the permissions when the filesystem is not mounted - doing it while mounted has never worked for me.

Additionly, you can add the 'user' option to your fstab, example:

```
/dev/mapper/db-db   /var/lib/mysql    ext3    relatime,user        0       2
```

This should also mean that the mount command (if it needs to be called) won't need root privileges to mount that volume. Not changing your fstab will not stop you fixing your issue though!

Comment: this is right answer

Answer (score 2):

I usually do this on empty unmounted directory

```
chmod 777 <directory>
```

Then do

```
chown -R mysql.mysql <directory>
```

Then in /etc/fstab do

```
<device>    <directory>  ext3   user,defaults 0 2
```

Then use

```
mount -a
```

to mount all filesystems listed in /etc/fstab.

This works for me. Give it a try

Comment: Hi @saudabh. You just saved me a few working hours on this very good answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to only do it as part of the `mount` command line, you can use the `-o` switch and do:

```
mount device mount-point -o uid=foo
```

That will change the owner of the mount point to user `foo` instead of root.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had fallen into a similar problem. And this is what I did:

**In the /etc/fstab:**

UUID=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx  /mnt/minimal_dev_env  ext4 errors=remount-ro  0  2

**In My Ubuntu Clipboard Extension:**

Added this following *COMBINED* command:

sudo mount -a && sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /mnt/minimal_dev_env/mysql && sudo systemctl restart mysql && ls -la /mnt/minimal_dev_env/mysql

for mounting. And,

sudo systemctl stop mysql && sudo umount /mnt/minimal_dev_env/ && ls -la /mnt/minimal_dev_env/

for unmounting.

Answer (score 0):

Would it work to set fstab entry like this?

```
/dev/mapper/db-db   /var/lib/mysql    ext3    relatime,mode=0755,uid=1000        0       2
```

where uid is ID of a user returned by "id" command.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `setfacl` to set permissions on a mount point.

I hit this issue with a manually created (via `udev` rules) `zram` device.

- To set `755` permissions with myself as owner:

```
sudo setfacl -m "u:stuart:rwx" /var/build/sources
sudo setfacl -m "g:stuart:rx" /var/build/sources
sudo setfacl -m "other:rx" /var/build/sources
```

[image: Testing setfacl permissions]

- source: [Arch Linux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Access_Control_Lists)